# Matlab Optimization Toolbox versus CVX?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, math-software, cvx

I would like to know what the difference between the Matlab Optimization Toolbox and [CVX](http://cvxr.com/), which is a convex optimization toolbox? Can a convex optimization problem be solved in both?

Answer (score 4):

Some differences:

1. Matlab optimization toolbox is priced at $1,150. CVX is free.
2. Matlab optimization toolbox implements a variety of general-purpose algorithms, beyond convex programming. CVX, as the name suggests, is restricted to convex programming. Moreover,  its enforcement of [disciplined convex programming](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/doc/dcp.html#dcp) means one can't just type in a formula for convex function: the user has to understand the reason for convexity *and* be able to demonstrate it to the program. Some beginning users find this difficult, as you can see from [CVX questions](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cvx) asked at [Computational Science.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

If convex optimization is all you need, 1 probably outweighs 2.